# One line in ArrayList isn't printed out

Tags: java, linked-list

My code has to read 50 lines of input and output them in reverse order, then other 50 lines, so output starts from 50th line, goes to the 1st one, then it start from 100th line to 50th I got it to work. But the only thing, that 51 line isn't printed, I can't get what's going wrong.

```
public static void doIt(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {
    String newString;
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    int i = 0;
    while ((newString = r.readLine()) != null) {
        if (i < 50) {
            i++;
            list.addFirst(newString);
        } else {
            for (String s : list)
                w.println(s);
            list.clear();
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    for (String s : list)
        w.println(s);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are discarding the line you read when i == 50, here is a fix that makes it work.

```
public static void doIt(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {

String newString;
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
int i = 0;
while ((newString = r.readLine()) != null) {
    if (i < 50) {
        i++;
        list.addFirst(newString);
    } else {
        for (String s : list)
            w.println(s);
        list.clear();
        list.addFirst(newString); // <---- add this line and you should be fine
        i = 0;
    }
}

for (String s : list)
    w.println(s);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as follow:

```
 i++; 
list.addFirst(newString);
```

to

```
list.addFirst(newString); 
 i++;
```

Because the way you are adding **newString** to list will skip one count

**Update:**

Sorry but I have to fix my answer rather than deleting this. I checked it twice and as per the right answer add this line :-)

```
list.addFirst(newString);
```

Comment: Yes he is incrementing and then only adding. but he has to do the other way around

Comment: to me there is no difference I will wait :)

Comment: And hence he is not getting the first element which is supposed to be the 51st one.

Comment: @Nabin hey, thanks for that, but it doesn't work, also i isn't an index, it's just integer that keeps number of strings

Comment: @user2847624 Yes I know **i** is not an index.

Comment: Im sorry Nabin, but this is not true. The two statements order does not change anything in this case.